# react native pagination with search using flatlist and hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native

react native search using search key send as parameter for Api call which was text input in search filled and along with it react native pagination using Flatlist and hook , problem faced that i have added data when next page loaded,  but during seach key enter it stored its previous value

Comment: Hi can you send me screenshot of your code so that I can help you

Comment: const [data, setData] = useState([]);const [page,setPage] =useState(1);const [searchingKey, setSearchingKey]=useState(); <TextInput onChangeText={(val)=>setSearchingKey(val)}/> const getData =() =>{  axios.get("url&page"+page,{searchKey: searchingKey}).then(response){setData([...data, ...response.data]}}}

Comment: <FlatList data={data} onEnd={setPage(page+1) onEndreachThreshold={0.1}/>                   here searching key send as parameter for which is text input value stored in useState hook and then send to api call , but during search key changing data changes but due to [...data, ...response.data] for pagination dada concat previous data not altered and it remains stored in useState

Answer (score 0):

When you type on input search, you first should reset data state: setData([]).
setData is async and api request also, then, it is possible than reset failed some times.
For this reason, I use flags with useRef, to write and read value synchronous way, example:

```
const resetData = useRef(false)
```

when type on filter:

```
 resetData.current=true
```

and on .then api req:

```
if(resetData.current){
 setData(response.data);
 resetData.current = false
}
else{
 setData([...data,response.data])
}
```

Edit(after your comments):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
//..other imports

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState();
  const resetData = useRef(false);

  const getData = () => {
    let pageToReq = page;
    if (resetData.current) {
      pageToReq = 0;
    }
    const headers = { Authorization: "token" };
    axios
      .get("baseurl" + "getdata?page=" + pageToReq, { searchingKey: searchKey })
      .then(async function (response) {
        if (resetData.current) {
          setData(response.data);
          resetData.current = false;
        } else {
          setData([...data, ...response.data]);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [page, searchKey]);

  const handleOnChangeText = (val) => {
    resetData.current = true;
    setSearchKey(val);
  };

  const handleOnEnd = () => {
    if (resetData.current) {
      return;
    }
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={handleOnChangeText} />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        onEnd={handleOnEnd}
        onEndReachThreshold={0.1}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState();

const getData = () =>{
const headers ={
Authorization: token,
}
axios.get("baseurl"+ "getdata?page=" + page,{
searchingKey: searchKey,
})
.then(async function(response){
setData([...data, ...response.data]);
})
.catch(function (error){
consoloe.log(error)})
}
useEffect(() =>{
   getData();
}, [page]);
return(
<View>
<TextInput 
onChangeText ={(val) =>setSearchKey(val)}
/>
<FlatList 
data={data}
onEnd={setPage(page+1)}
onEndReachThreshold={0.1}
>

Comment: during data concatinaton it should stored its previous data in state varialbe ,as a result when changes the search parameter as a result it should show previous data along with its new data ,,,,i only want new dada to render

Comment: thanks but it is not showing the desired result after search key is entered and data not show as expected for searching

Comment: actually the current page get increased ,then i put condition if(lastPage> page){setPage(page+1)} ,but the searchable item found two times ... after blanking the searchKey and when i come back from another page the same data rendred please help